# How to combine dated data rows in SAS?

Tags: sas, longitudinal

I have longitudinal data, but I wish to combine rows if the value of one variable is the same, and update the time variable so that the start and finish time reflects the combined time period. At the end of this only the combined rows and unique rows are kept.

Here is an example

Data have:

| Person | Start | Finish | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1/1/1988 | 31/12/1988 | 78 |
| A | 1/1/1989 | 31/12/1989 | 78 |
| A | 1/1/1990 | 31/12/1990 | 78 |
| A | 1/1/1991 | 31/12/1991 | 81 |
| A | 1/1/1992 | 31/12/1992 | 82 |
| A | 1/1/1993 | 31/12/1993 | 82 |
| B | 1/1/1968 | 31/12/1968 | 56 |
| B | 1/1/1969 | 31/12/1969 | 55 |
| B | 1/1/1970 | 31/12/1970 | 55 |

Data want:

| Person | Start | Finish | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1/1/1988 | 31/12/1990 | 78 |
| A | 1/1/1991 | 31/12/1991 | 81 |
| A | 1/1/1992 | 31/12/1993 | 82 |
| B | 1/1/1968 | 31/12/1968 | 56 |
| B | 1/1/1969 | 31/12/1970 | 55 |

What would be the best way of doing this? Thank you all for your time!

Comment: Is the combination only driven by constant values of WEIGHT?  Or does it matter whether or not the date intervals intersect at all?

Comment: It is only driven by WEIGHT, the original data is collected at regular time intervals therefore the date intervals shouldn't intersect for a given PERSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will produce your required results from the sample data. It relies on the data being correctly sorted by `start` and `finish`.

```
data want (keep=person start finish weight);
    set have (rename= (start=original_start finish=original_finish)); * rename so that the names do not clash with the final variable names;
    by person weight notsorted;                                       * assumes that the data are sorted by START and FINISH dates;
    retain start;                                                     * remembers this variable WHILE we read multiple rows;
    format start finish ddmmyy10.;
    if first.weight then start=original_start;                        * record the first START date of each combination of PERSON and WEIGHT;
    if last.weight then do;
        finish=original_finish;                                       * record the last FINISH date;
        output;                                                       * only output when we have read the last row for this combination of PERSON and WEIGHT;
    end;
run;
```

If your real data has complications like overlapping time periods then you could use `proc summary` to get the result:

```
* use PROC SUMMARY to calculate minimum and maximum for START and FINISH. Only keep the minimum for START and the maximum for FINISH;
proc summary data=have nway;
    class person weight;
    var start finish;
    output out=want2 (drop=_type_ _freq_ min_finish max_start) min=start min_finish max=max_start finish;

run;
```

or if you need to keep the rows in the same order you can replace `class person weight;` 
 with `by person weight notsorted;` but this will cause issues if the rows containing the same `person` and `weight` values are not all together in the dataset.

```
proc summary data=have nway;
    by person weight notsorted;
    var start finish;
    output out=want2 (drop=_type_ _freq_ min_finish max_start) min=start min_finish max=max_start finish;

run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the data values for a person contain a time ordered pattern such as

`X X X Y X X`

and you want 3 rows, 1 for each contiguous period of same valued data values.

You can use DOW processing to compute the start and finish of each contiguous group.

Example:

```
data have;
input Person $  Start ddmmyy10. Finish  ddmmyy10. Weight;
format start finish ddmmyy10.;
datalines;
A   1/1/1988    31/12/1988  78
A   1/1/1989    31/12/1989  78
A   1/1/1990    31/12/1990  78
A   1/1/1991    31/12/1991  81
A   1/1/1992    31/12/1992  82
A   1/1/1993    31/12/1993  82
B   1/1/1968    31/12/1968  56
B   1/1/1969    31/12/1969  55
B   1/1/1970    31/12/1970  55
;

proc sort data=have;
  by person start;
data want(keep=person start finish weight);
  do until (last.weight);
    set have;
    by person weight notsorted;
    if first.weight then gstart=start;
  end;
  start = gstart;
run;
```

[image]